# crash during protocol buffers initialization

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

The following crash observed with my application using protocol buffers

0x00000000 in ?? ()
0x08055f43 in google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile (
encoded_file_descriptor=0xf64, size=3940) at once.h:115

0x08072b7a in google::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescrip
tor_2eproto () at google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc:557

Comment: Okay. Do you have a question perhaps?

Comment: How can we know the way you are using PB without any code to see? `my application using protocol buffers` doesn't tell much. Please edit your question and include some code relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Met the exact same crash as you described. The reason is mixed `Release` verion of `libprotobuf.lib` with `Debug` runtime under VC 2008. Further discussion in http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=184 .

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i'v met same problem.

Why it happend:
I had two .proto files with same relative path/name in different libraries (different packages):
lib1/proto/config.proto, lib2/proto/config.proto

The solution is obvious - put your .proto files in different directories and/or have unique .proto filenames.

PS: i know it's four year old question, but I hope it help to someone else.